# Opera Mini keeps saying awaiting transfer on downloads

Tags: downloads, opera-mini

I use Opera mini on my windows phone to save on data almost all the time. I also use Edge to browse at times. However sometimes when I want to download some thing like an audio on the Opera Mini apps it keeps showing "Awaiting Transfer" forever and its on WiFi.

I had thought the problem was battery but my battery was 85%. But when I turned WiFi off and turned Mobile data it downloaded very well. Please help me understand why Opera mini has the annoying behavior. I like using it over Edge because of its data saving mode.